# cannot show header text of primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the below code, but find that the `headerText` doesn't show. Any advice?

```
<p:dataTable var="toDoList" value="#{dtView}" tableStyle="width:auto" >
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row><p:column  headerText="#{toDoList.schoolScrn}">
            <p:outputLabel value="#{toDoList.schoolScrn}" />
        </p:column></p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable var="info" value="#{toDoList.infoList}" >
            <p:column >
                <h:outputText value="#{info}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Do you need the <p:outputLabel value="#{toDoList.schoolScrn}" /> ? Try without it.

Comment: All rows  share one header in column so you can't change in every iteration by `#{toDoList.schoolScrn}`. This list consists probably of values you want to display so it shouldn't be in header. I guess you misunderstands something. Try adding static values like [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/group.xhtml) and then if you want dynamic ones look at `private List<Integer> years` in given link which is used in `<p:column headerText="#{year}" />` by `<ui:repeat value="#{dtGroupView.years}" var="year">`.

Comment: solved by using ui repeater